# I don't understand how to append JSON object data to an Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have a JSON response from an API, an example of which can be seen below.  In the example, `question_groups` contains 3 groups named `DDD`, `FED`, and `IPE`, and within each group is a `questions` array.  In reality, there are more than 3 groups and most groups contain 5 or more questions.

I can display each `question` & its corresponding `response` in the order in which each group appears in JSON, but I don't understand how I can apply each group and its subsequent questions to an accordion.  I can create an accordion which displays each group on a new layer/tab, but each layer/tab contains all questions from all groups.  I want to make it that each accordion layer is titled with one `group_name` and is populated with the questions from that group.

Here is my code for displaying the questions data.  This code differentiates between questions which require a users written input and a select option.

```
const TextQuestion = ({ title, question }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
        <TextField variant="outlined" label={title} value={question?.Question || ""} />
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="Response" />
    </Box>
  );
};

const SelectQuestion = ({ title, question }) => {
  return (
    <Box>
        <TextField variant="outlined" multiline label={title} value={question?.Question || ""} />
        <Select label="Question" autoWidth >
          {question.Choices.map((choice) => (
            <MenuItem key={choice} value={choice}>
              {choice}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
    </Box>
  );
};

const questionComps = questions["question_groups"]?.map((group, i) => {
  return group["questions"]?.map((question, i) => {
    return question["QuestionType"] === "Text" ? (
      <Box>
        <TextQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} title={group["GroupName"]} question={question} />
        <Divider />
      </Box>
    ) : (
        <Box>
          <SelectQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} title={group["GroupName"]} question={question} />
          <Divider />
        </Box>
    );
  });
});
```

My accordion

```
<Accordion style={{ marginTop: "10px", addingLeft: "10px", }} >
  <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
    <Typography>{group?.GroupName}</Typography>
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>{questionComps}</AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

The example of my JSON

```
    {
      "question_groups": [
        {
          "GroupName": "DDD",
          "questions": [
            {
              "Question": "Do you want a drink",
              "QuestionType": "Single Choice",
              "Response": null,
              "Choices": [
                "Yes",
                "No"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "SizingId": null
        },
        {
          "GroupName": "FED",
          "questions": [
            {
              "Question": "What do you want to drink",
              "QuestionType": "Single Choice",
              "Response": null,
              "Choices": [
                null
              ]
            },
            {
              "Question": "Place your drinks order",
              "QuestionType": "Text",
              "Response": null,
              "Choices": [
                null
              ]
            }
          ],
          "SizingId": null
        },
        {
          "GroupName": "IPE",
          "questions": [
            {
              "Question": "Would you like something to eat?",
              "QuestionType": "Single Choice",
              "Response": null,
              "Choices": [
                "No",
                "Yes"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "SizingId": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format. When you call `JSON.parse()`, you convert that string into a normal JavaScript object.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Thanks for the info.  I have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: You're welcome. But your title is still not quite accurate. There is also no such thing as JSON data. You just have an object. You are asking how to add object data to an accordion.

Comment: Please let me know if the updated more accurately describes my question.

Comment: I see Ciaran had an issue mapping representations of data or using existing ones:  there is a JSON object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), the API allows you to convert data from one representation to another: parse, from a JSON string to JS object, and stringify, from a JS object to a JSON string. Responses from servers are in string format, so parsing is what you need, as Scott suggested. Please remove the "data" word from your question title, as the "object" word already specifies the data type. And, change append to format.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping the group names to the `accordion summary` and then mapping through the questions inside the `accordion details` results in the desired layout rendered.

```
    const questionComps = questions["question_groups"]?.map((group, i) => {
        return (
            <Accordion
                style={{
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    paddingLeft: "10px",
                }}
            >
                <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
                    <Typography>{group?.GroupName}</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
                    {group["questions"]?.map((question, j) => {
                        return question["QuestionType"] === "Text" ? (
                            <Box>
                                <TextQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} title={group["GroupName"]} question={question} />
                                <Divider />
                            </Box>
                        ) : (
                            <Box>
                                <SelectQuestion
                                    key={`${j}${question.Question}`}
                                    title={group["GroupName"]}
                                    question={question}
                                />
                                <Divider />
                            </Box>
                        );
                    })}
                </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
        );
    });
```